# Origami: What shapes are impossible?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, origami

Let's say we had a collection of pieces of rectangular paper of any size to choose from. Using one sheet only of any chosen size, what three-dimensional (or two-dimensional) shapes are impossible to construct with only the allowance of folding and gluing?

Comment: Why are you not interested in possible shapes

Comment: Watch the TED Talk ["Robert Lang: The math and magic of origami"](https://www.ted.com/talks/robert_lang_folds_way_new_origami), and you might just end-up believing that *no* shapes are impossible.  :)

Comment: Maybe... circle?

Comment: Origami and gluing? Please...

Comment: Good point... I guess there's no gluing in Origami!

Answer (score 1):

No self-intersection at overlaps.  A sheet cannot penetrate a fold.  So no Klein-Bottles is one example.